# Javascript color gradient even split, blue to grey to red

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, interpolation, gradient

Using javascript / D3, I am trying to map colors to a color gradient running from red to grey to blue as shown below.[image]

This is taken from the Algo Vis paper [Algo Vis](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-Algebraic-Process-for-Visualization-Design-Kindlmann-Scheidegger/3d1a121a52cd313cb79c256cb0f6227ca6fc175c/pdf)
slide 13. However I am having trouble producing this gradient. I have tried
creating two gradients from blue to grey and grey to red, as follows, but my result is off.

```
botRgb = d3.rgb(0,0,210);
topRgb = d3.rgb(210,0,0);
midRgb = d3.rgb(230,230,230);
gradient1 = d3.interpolateRgb(botRgb,midRgb);
gradient2 = d3.interpolateRgb(midRgb,topRgb);
// assume x is from 0 to 1
if (x < 0.5){
  return gradient1(x)
} else {
  return gradient2(x)
}
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [d3.scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale). In particular, the [continuous domain](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_domain) feature allows one to create a domain -- in your case, you said your x is from 0 to 1 -- and assign equivalents to that domain in the range.

Something like:

```
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 0.5, 1.0])
    .range(["blue", "white", "red"]);

// use with color(x) where x is from 0 to 1;
```

Perhaps replacing the color keywords with rgb values.